# Free JVM profilers for websites

Tags: java, profiling

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Open Source Java Profilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948549/open-source-java-profilers)
>   [Please recommend a Java profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762/please-recommend-a-java-profiler)

I'm looking for a JVM profiler (preferably open source) so I can look at the heap and cpu usage of my personal website.

I've used Lambda Probe, and I like it because it provides a web interface for my remote Unix computer that has no display. I was wondering what else is available

Also, it would be helpful if I could see specific memory and cpu usage.

Thanks,

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762/please-recommend-a-java-profiler

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392203/looking-for-recommendations-for-end-to-end-java-cpu-profilers

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've looked through those sites.

Comment: If none of those have what you are looking for then you should edit your question with more specific details; as it is your question is exactly the same.

Comment: None of them really match what I like about Lambda Probe (web interface that lets me monitor a remote unix machine)
If I'm going about this the wrong way, let me know because I'm learning this as I go.

Comment: All these profilers can be attached to remote processes. So you run your profiler on your local computer and it can profile an application on your unix box.

Comment: I'm also looking for one that gives me more than general information ie specific memory and cpu usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked Netbeans profiler and/or Eclipse TPTP. Both are worth trying and they are very good.

http://profiler.netbeans.org/

http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/

Comment: Additional link: http://java-source.net/open-source/profilers